# dbcc checkdb gives error "Incorrect PFS free space information for page"

Tags: sql-server, errors, dbcc, dbcc-checkdb

dbcc checkdb

query for database gives errors. What is it, is it dangerous and how to resolve?

Full log file: [download file](https://mega.nz/#!O5FzHThL!WcUZq5jdfLHXkbQNT2dO2-hbBYVNHNZm5fHKYQXoHEc) or [view on github](https://gist.github.com/Gennady-G/e0b66fe9a585740ecbafade6b6ac8d68) (errors begin from string 364)

Possible 
There was disk d:\ crash before (there are .mdf and .ldf files on d:\Data). Disk was restored from backup. But not sure if these errors are related with this hardware crash.

> DBCC results for 'DocStreams'. Msg 8914, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect PFS free space information for page (1:103151) in object ID
>   1993058136, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594434682880, alloc unit ID
>   71906736119218176 (type LOB data). Expected value   0_PCT_FULL, actual
>   value 100_PCT_FULL. Msg 8914, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect PFS
>   free space information for page (1:103887) in object ID 1993058136,
>   index ID 1, partition ID 72057594434682880, alloc unit ID
>   71906736119218176 (type LOB data). Expected value   0_PCT_FULL, actual
>   value 100_PCT_FULL. Msg 8914, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect PFS
>   free space information for page (1:104839) in object ID 1993058136,
>   index ID 1, partition ID 72057594434682880, alloc unit ID
>   71906736119218176 (type LOB data). Expected value   0_PCT_FULL, actual
>   value 100_PCT_FULL.

[image]

Comment: You potentially need to patch your database server ([ref](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-bug-that-people-are-hitting-msg-8914-pfs-free-space/)) as you could be running into a bug with the free-space tracking algorithm.  This will hopefully resolve the issue going forward.  To fix the error itself, try rebuilding the clustered index on the DocStreams table.

Comment: And Yes You are right, it could be just bug: "as long as the message tells you that the page is supposed to be empty, but is actually marked 100%, nothing can really go wrong with that page. Unfortunately, DBCC will keep reporting these errors." from Your link

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for response John!

Tried to backup DB and rebuild clustered index, but didn't help. As I understand there is no patch, but it is and old bug. Or something was really damaged during hardware crash..

This helped:

```
--dbcc checkdb;
--dbcc checktable(DocStreams) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;

ALTER DATABASE WSS_Content
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

dbcc checktable(DocStreams, REPAIR_FAST) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;
GO
dbcc checktable(DocStreams, REPAIR_REBUILD) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;

-- use this only if above does not work
--DBCC CHECKTABLE(DocStreams, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;

ALTER DATABASE WSS_Content SET MULTI_USER;
```

**But first**

- Do backup database
- I also backuped table using this cmd (press Enter multiple times):

  bcp WSS_Content.dbo.DocStreams out C:\backups\DocStreams\DocStreams.dat -t -T

  pause

Use in Your own risk)

links:
  [incorrect-pfs](http://udayarumilli.com/sql-server-incorrect-pfs-free-space-information-for-page-1xxxx-in-object-id-xxxxxx/)
  [bcp tool](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/)

Upd.: or You can try "reorganize with (lob_compaction = on)" first ([link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-bug-that-people-are-hitting-msg-8914-pfs-free-space/))